C# DbContext configuration for multiple entities mapping to the same base entity and table with different query filters
I'm trying to map multiple entities that inherit from the same entity to different DbSets but live in the same table.
For example I have the following entity, where base entity simply defines common fields I want in all tables of my database:
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class RegistryEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string? LegalName { get; set; }
    public string Denomination { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public bool IsCustomer { get; set; }
    public bool IsSupplier { get; set; }
    public bool IsPerson { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorporation { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerEntity : RegistryEntity
{
}

public class SupplierEntity : RegistryEntity
{
}

With the following configurations
public class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.Property(b => b.CreatedOn).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(b => b.UpdatedOn).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow).IsConcurrencyToken();
    }
}

public class RegistryEntityConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<RegistryEntity>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RegistryEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("registries");
        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}

And I'd like to have SupplierEntity mapping to registries table where IsSupplier is true, same thing with Customer where IsCustomer is true, I'd also like to add CorporationEntity with a subset of the columns of the registry table.
This is probably answered so many times but I can't seem to make a specific solution for this.
If it may be possible I'd like for Suppliers and Customers to have only Denomination and IsCorporation and IsPerson
I've tried with multiple sort of the following code
public class SupplierEntityConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<SupplierEntity>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SupplierEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("registries")
            .HasQueryFilter(s => s.IsSupplier);
    }
}

public class CustomerEntityConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<CustomerEntity>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CustomerEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("registries")
            .HasQueryFilter(s => s.IsCustomer);
    }
}

But I keep getting the following error when trying to add a migration:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The filter expression 'c => c.IsCustomer' cannot be specified for entity type 'CustomerEntity'. A filter may only be applied to the root entity type 'RegistryEntity'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728


The error indicates the property can only be applied to the base class (root entity) and not to the inherited class.  I think you need to change from : BaseEntityConfiguration to : BaseEntityConfiguration

You don't need the global query filter. If you do TPH inheritance correctly EF will filter the DbSets automatically.
